# failsafe for networked robot

Tags: php, robotics

I have a robot that I'm controlling via a browser. A page with buttons to go forward, reverse, etc is written in PHP hosted on an onboard computer. The PHP is just sending ASCII characters over a serial connection to a microcontroller. Anyway, I need to implement a failsafe so that when the person driving it gets disconnected, the robot will stop. The only thing I can think to do is to ping the person on the web page or something, but I'm sure there is a better way than that. The robot is connected either via an ad hoc network or a regular wireless network that is connected to the internet. Obviously if I go with the ping method then there will have to be a delay between the actual time disconnected and when it realizes it's been disconnected. I'd like this delay to be a small as possible, whatever the method used. I'd appreciate any ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest you use a simple flash object embedded in the web browser to open a **socket connection** to a server on the robot?   The server can be written in any suitable language - even PHP (cough).

Then it is a simple matter to detect immediately when the connection goes down, and implement your fail-safe approach.

HTTP is not a ideal protocol for robot control.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Pinging a web client is somewhat unreliable, for you have to take into account, that the client ip might change.

On the other hand, you could emulate a "dead-man-button" via Ajax. Let the webpage send a defined command every now and then (maybe every 5 to 10 seconds). If the robot doesn't receive the message for some time, it can stop. The Ajax script could run in the background so the controlling user won't even notice anything.

This would of course mean, that your robot needs to have a counter which is incremented every second and reset when the message is received. The moment the timer variable is too high, FULL STOP

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is to include ajax code in your HTML that "pings" your server every X second. I believe that's what Facebook Chat does to know whether or not you are still online.

HTML 5 Web sockets might be the solution you are looking for but you have to consider that it won't be implemented by most of your users' browsers.

You might find this article interesting: http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/12/websockets-vs-comet-ajax.

Comment: Facebook uses Comet which uses a sustained http connection